# Generate right schema and documentation with Tapir and sealed traits

Tags: scala, openapi, circe, tapir

I have the following endpoint:

```scala
  val myEndpoint: PublicEndpoint[Unit, ErrorResponse, Entity, Any] = endpoint.get
    .in("test")
    .out(jsonBody[Entity])
    .errorOut(jsonBody[ErrorResponse])
```

Where `Entity` and `ErrorResponse` are:

```scala
sealed trait ErrorResponse
object ErrorResponse {
  final case class NotFound(id: String) extends ErrorResponse
  final case class UnknownError(error: String) extends ErrorResponse

  implicit val notFoundSchema: Schema[NotFound] = Schema.derived
  implicit val unknownErrorSchema: Schema[UnknownError] = Schema.derived
  implicit val errorResponseSchema: Schema[ErrorResponse] = Schema.derived
}
```

Then I convert the endpoints to akka routes:

```scala
  val myEndpointRoute: Route = AkkaHttpServerInterpreter().toRoute(myEndpoint.serverLogic { _ =>
    val result: Either[ErrorResponse, Entity] = Right(Entity("some data of the entity"))
    Future.successful(result)
  })

  val swaggerEndpoint = SwaggerInterpreter().fromEndpoints[Future](List(myEndpoint), "Tapir Demo", "1.0")
  val swaggerRoutes: Route = AkkaHttpServerInterpreter().toRoute(swaggerEndpoint)
```

And run the server:

```scala
  Http()
    .newServerAt("localhost", 8080)
    .bind(myEndpointRoute ~ swaggerRoutes)
    .onComplete {
      case Success(_) =>
        println(s"Started on port 8080")
      case Failure(e) =>
        println("Failed to start ... ", e)
    }
```

The issue I have is when browsing the schema for `ErrorResponse` I see an hierarchy of objects (`#0` and `#1`) instead of subtypes like `NotFound`, `UnknownError`.

[image]

How should I define the schema for `ErrorResponse`?

PS: dependencies:

```scala
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-core" % "1.9.6",
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-json-circe" % "1.9.6"
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-swagger-ui-bundle"  % "1.9.6",
  "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-akka-http-server" % "1.9.6"
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is bothering you. The naming #0 and #1? Otherwise it seems to match your definition: it's one of two objects definition. Did you expand #0 and #1? They should match your types definition.

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ, sorry if it's not clear and thanks for taking time for answering. Yes, I would expect to see "NotFound" and "UnknowError" instead of "#0" and "#1".

Comment: Have you checked the OpenAPI yaml generated by Tapir? Just to check if it's SwaggerUI choosing these names or Tapir (or somehow Circe). If the latter, you can consider opening a discussion on their GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how [swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) renders [oneOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) in [OpenAPI Spec 3.1.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md), which is the one that [tapir](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir) uses as the default version. If you change it to [OpenAPI Spec 3.0.3](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md) or any **3.x.x** you will get the result you expect. Here you have a POC that reproduce your case (I used pekko-http instead of akka-http, but it's the same)

- **build.sbt**

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "tapir-swagger-ui-poc",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "ch.qos.logback"                 % "logback-classic"         % "1.4.14",
      "com.typesafe.scala-logging"    %% "scala-logging"           % "3.9.5",
      "org.apache.pekko"              %% "pekko-actor-typed"       % "1.0.2",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir"   %% "tapir-pekko-http-server" % "1.9.6",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir"   %% "tapir-sttp-stub-server"  % "1.9.6",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir"   %% "tapir-openapi-docs"      % "1.9.6",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir"   %% "tapir-json-circe"        % "1.9.6",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir"   %% "tapir-swagger-ui-bundle" % "1.9.6",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.apispec" %% "openapi-circe-yaml"      % "0.7.3"
    ),
    run / fork := true
  )
```

- **Main.scala**

```scala
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import org.apache.pekko.http.scaladsl.Http
import org.apache.pekko.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import sttp.tapir._
import sttp.tapir.json.circe._
import sttp.tapir.server.ServerEndpoint
import sttp.tapir.server.pekkohttp.PekkoHttpServerInterpreter
import sttp.tapir.swagger.SwaggerUIOptions
import sttp.tapir.swagger.bundle.SwaggerInterpreter

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}

object Main {

  sealed trait ErrorResponse

  object ErrorResponse {
    final case class NotFound(id: String) extends ErrorResponse

    final case class UnknownError(error: String) extends ErrorResponse

    implicit val notFoundSchema: Schema[NotFound] = Schema.derived
    implicit val unknownErrorSchema: Schema[UnknownError] = Schema.derived
    implicit val errorResponseSchema: Schema[ErrorResponse] = Schema.derived
  }

  private val myEndpoint = endpoint.get
    .in("test")
    .out(stringBody)
    .errorOut(jsonBody[ErrorResponse])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val logger = Logger(getClass)

    implicit val system: ActorSystem[Nothing] =
      ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "money-maniacs-http")

    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor =
      system.executionContext

    /**
     * swagger UI endpoints for OpenAPI Spec 3.0.3
     */
    val swaggerEndpoints_3_0_3: List[ServerEndpoint[Any, Future]] =
      SwaggerInterpreter(
        customiseDocsModel = openAPI => openAPI.openapi("3.0.3"), // set OpenAPI spec version
        swaggerUIOptions = SwaggerUIOptions.default.pathPrefix(List("docs-3.0.3")) // set path prefix for docs
      )
      .fromEndpoints[Future](
        List(myEndpoint), // list of endpoints 
        "My App", 
        "1.0"
      )

    /**
     * swagger UI endpoints for OpenAPI Spec 3.1.0
     */
    val swaggerEndpoints_3_1_0: List[ServerEndpoint[Any, Future]] =
      SwaggerInterpreter(
        swaggerUIOptions = SwaggerUIOptions.default.pathPrefix(List("docs-3.1.0")) // set path prefix for docs
      )
      .fromEndpoints[Future](
        List(myEndpoint), // list of endpoints
        "My App", 
        "1.0"
      )

    val routes: Route =
      PekkoHttpServerInterpreter()
        .toRoute(swaggerEndpoints_3_0_3 ::: swaggerEndpoints_3_1_0)

    val interface = "0.0.0.0"
    val port = 9000

    Http()
      .newServerAt(interface = interface, port = port)
      .bind(routes)
      .foreach { _ =>
        logger.info(s"Server started at $interface:$port")
        logger.info(s"Press enter to stop the server")
      }
  }

}
```

Once you start the server with `sbt run` you can check the endpoints for OpenAPI Spec `3.1.0` and `3.0.3`

```bash
open http://localhost:9000/docs-3.0.3
```

[image]

```bash
open http://localhost:9000/docs-3.1.0
```

[image]

---

A [similar issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9055) was reported in Swagger. The suggestion was add the property **title** with the same name of the object.

For [tapir 1.9.6](https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/releases/tag/v1.9.6) which is the version you are using and the latest one released up to now, you can get the same result changing the schemas defined to something like

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf

implicit val notFoundSchema: Schema[NotFound] =
  Schema.derived.title(typeOf[NotFound].typeSymbol.name.toString)
implicit val unknownErrorSchema: Schema[UnknownError] =
  Schema.derived.title(typeOf[UnknownError].typeSymbol.name.toString)
implicit val errorResponseSchema: Schema[ErrorResponse] =
  Schema.derived.title(typeOf[UnknownError].typeSymbol.name.toString)
```

doing that, will produce the result you are looking for (the hash with the number stills there but now it also adds the description you want)

[image: OpenAPI Spec oneOf 3.1.0 with title]

Comment: Nice findings! I wonder if the `title`shouldn't always be set by Tapir. @OP maybe consider opening the discussion on Tapir's GitHub.

Comment: Hey Gastón, thank you very much !!! A lot of learn with your answer, thank you for your time and detailed solutions !!!

Comment: @GaëlJ I don't think this should be fixed from tapir. I would first try to open the discussion in swagger UI. At least understand why they changed how `oneOf` is rendered from one version to the other one.

Comment: I added an issue in tapir to see if adding "title" is feasible: https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/issues/3447

The issue in swagger-ui is closed, so I'm not sure if they plan to do anything about that?